# How come my active and visited links don't execute the desired command?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

It seemed like my regular a tag overrides the color set in active and visited.

So I set it to the corresponding default color in order to get a visual difference, yet it does not work when I visit the page.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4194b5 50%, #999b9b 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

a:visited {
  color: #4194b5;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #e5f4fc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

a:active {
  color: #4194b5;
}
```

I have this transition effect (that I use for the first time, new code to me) when you hover your mouse over the link, and I want to keep the blue color when you click the link, so it's clear you already visited that link.

Answer (score 0):

`color` doesn't override `-webkit-text-fill-color`. They are different properties.

If you want to change `-webkit-text-fill-color` on `:hover` then you need to do so with the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property.

Comment: so I should change the `color: #4194b5;` in a:visited, a:hover and a:active to `-webkit-text-fill-color: color: #4194b5;` ?